# The Pach Shemen and the Sotah

Tags: sources-mekorot, chanuka, sotah-secluded-woman, pirsumei-nissa

I remember hearing during a shiur on Neiros Shabbos and Chanukah...shalom bayis/Shabbos trumping pirsumei nisah/Chanukah, etc.

There was one source which said that the pach shemen was actually discovered behind some dislodged dirt or bricks used for the sotah's drink on the grounds of the mikdash.

Has anyone heard this and can you share the source?

Comment: I suspect that this comes from attempting to answer why the oil wasn't rendered impure by being moved by gentiles. One answer given is that the oil was in the ground where it wouldn't be moved. Cf. B'nei David to Hilkhot Hannukah (3:2).

Comment: related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/106998/11532