# Is there any connection between the Sotah, the Mizbeiach, and the Beis HaMikdash keychain?

Tags: beis-hamikdash, tractate-sotah, masechet-midot

In exactly three contexts, the Mishnah notes that there was an amah square marble slab with a ring, using exactly the same language each time.

The first is in [Sotah 2:2](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Sotah.2.2), regarding the Sotah procedure:

> נִכְנַס לַהֵיכָל וּפָנָה לִימִינוֹ, **וּמָקוֹם הָיָה שָׁם אַמָּה עַל אַמָּה, וְטַבְלָא שֶׁל שַׁיִשׁ, וְטַבַּעַת הָיְתָה קְבוּעָה בָהּ.** וּכְשֶׁהוּא מַגְבִּיהָהּ, נוֹטֵל עָפָר מִתַּחְתֶּיהָ וְנוֹתֵן כְּדֵי שֶׁיֵּרָאֶה עַל הַמַּיִם
>
> He entered the Heichal and turned to his right. **There was a place there, one amah by one amah, with a slab of marble, and a ring was fixed on it.** When he would lift it, he would take dirt from underneath it and place enough that it can be seen on the water.

The second is in [Middos 1:9](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Middot.1.9), regarding the procedure to lock up the Beis HaMikdash; the previous Mishnah identifies this place as the Fire Chamber:

> **וּמָקוֹם הָיָה שָׁם, אַמָּה עַל אַמָּה, וְטַבְלָא שֶׁל שַׁיִשׁ וְטַבַּעַת הָיְתָה קְבוּעָה בָהּ,** וְשַׁלְשֶׁלֶת שֶׁהַמַּפְתְּחוֹת הָיוּ תְלוּיוֹת בָּהּ. הִגִּיעַ זְמַן הַנְּעִילָה, הִגְבִּיהַּ אֶת הַטַּבְלָא בַּטַּבַּעַת וְנָטַל אֶת הַמַּפְתְּחוֹת מִן הַשַּׁלְשֶׁלֶת, וְנָעַל הַכֹּהֵן מִבִּפְנִים
>
> **There was a place there, one amah by one amah, with a slab of marble, and a ring was fixed on it,** and a chain on which the keys would hang. When the closing time came, he would lift the slab by the ring and take the keys from the chain, and the Kohen would lock from the inside.

The third is in [Middos 3:3](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Middot.3.3), regarding the pit under the Mizbeiach where the bloods would flow into the Kidron:

> לְמַטָּה בָרִצְפָה בְּאוֹתָהּ הַקֶּרֶן, **מָקוֹם הָיָה שָׁם אַמָּה עַל אַמָּה, וְטַבְלָא שֶׁל שַׁיִשׁ, וְטַבַּעַת הָיְתָה קְבוּעָה בָהּ,** שֶׁבּוֹ יוֹרְדִין לַשִּׁית וּמְנַקִּין אוֹתוֹ.
>
> Under the floor in that corner, **there was a place there, one amah by one amah, with a slab of marble, and a ring was fixed on it,** through which they would descend into the pit and clean it.

Is it just that these three things require access to underneath, and this was an elegant way to provide access without looking ugly? Or is there something deeper (so to speak) which connects these three things?

Comment: reasked at https://judaism.codidact.com/q/277055

Answer (score -2):

The Sotah, the Mizbeiach (altar), and the Beis HaMikdash (Holy Temple) are all significant elements in Jewish tradition and history, but there is no direct or inherent connection between them and a Beis HaMikdash keychain.

The Sotah is a ritual described in the Torah that is performed when a woman is suspected of committing adultery. The Mizbeiach, or altar, is a central element in Jewish worship, particularly during the times when the Holy Temple in Jerusalem stood. The Beis HaMikdash, or Holy Temple, was the central sanctuary of ancient Judaism, where sacrifices were offered and other religious ceremonies were performed[.](https://cemca.org.in/category/entertainment/)

A Beis HaMikdash keychain is a modern item that is meant to serve as a reminder of the history and significance of the Holy Temple, particularly for Jews who are unable to visit the Temple Mount in Jerusalem.

While the Sotah, the Mizbeiach, and the Beis HaMikdash all hold important places in Jewish tradition and history, they are distinct and separate concepts. However, a Beis HaMikdash keychain could be seen as a symbolic representation of the centrality of the Temple in Jewish life and the importance of Jewish tradition and history.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).